# Is it possible with Next.js 14 to update the app state in the browser from the server in real-time without the use of WebSocket?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, websocket, state

Is it possible with Next.js 14 to update the app state in the browser from the server in real-time without the use of WebSocket? The late versions of Next.js have got more capabilities to mix and match client and server parts of app. I'm wondering if it's possible now not to use WebSockets to update Next.js app state in the browser from server in real-time, and use Next.js for this instead? (for example with a result of delayed processing on the server)